# Flutter API fandom 1.0.1 not working, how do i make it work?

Tags: flutter, api, flutter-packages

Does anyone use **fandom: ^1.0.1** **API**?
I am trying to use it but for me, it's **not working**.
If anyone has solutions for this issue, please share how can I use it and share examples if possible.

Comment: The package is really outdated. Last it was published 19months ago. So you need to code it yourself.

Comment: Yea, like @KamrulHasanJony has said, this will be almost impossible for you to get it to work because it is very outdated and Flutter has moved forward since then, including but definitely not limited to Dart getting sound null safety.